# Calculate height of relative element with its absolute elements

Tags: jquery

I want to calculate the relative positioned section height which contains absolute positioned elements. None of the similar posts had an answer.
I thought that it would be a solution if I find the bottom position of the last child, and I give the same bottom position to the parent.

Furthermore, the nicest way would be if the height is recalculated by changing window width or height (because some of the children's widths or heights are in percentage and the x or y coordinates are changing). But this is not important.
How could I do it with jquery?

Here is an image about a simple example for better understanding (sorry, I called "object" instead of "element" due to my English) :
[image]

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: red;
}

.bg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 15%;
  top: 100px;
  right: 10%;
  background: green;
}

article {
  position: absolute;
  width: 35%;
  top: 200px;
  right: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class='bg'></div>
  <article class='txt'>Sed id erat dolor. Etiam fermentum ac nibh at faucibus. Suspendisse in mauris sodales, aliquet arcu mollis, viverra lacus. Sed enim nibh, bibendum a tortor quis, feugiat viverra orci. Nam rutrum interdum purus, eget fermentum lorem porta non. Sed maximus
    erat enim, a mattis quam convallis in. Donec congue semper augue, vel tincidunt eros auctor placerat.</article>
</section>
```

Comment: do you want to calculate a page's ALL sections' rights or only this one's?

Comment: @Sarout If you can tell how to calculate **only this section**, then I would give that bottom position to this one and I could repeat it with each (all sections will have different heights, so different bottom position of course). I am curious of the sections bottom, not the whole document bottom.

Comment: ok wait for me I think I found it.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, if you don't mean to do this I can edit, but as I understand, you should:

get the absolute element's `height` + `top` so it calculates the farthest point, which is the last thing in the parent element.
But, the element can be not outside the parent section, if so we just need to get the height of `section`.

```
if (x.css('position') == "absolute") {
  let height = parseFloat(x.css('height')) + parseFloat(x.css('top'));
  if (height < parseFloat(x.parent().css('height'))) {
    return parseFloat(x.parent().css('height'))
  }
  return height;
}
```

example: (**NOTE**: this only work on page loads, so if you change the height the variable will not get updated, you have to make an eventListener)

```js
function getHeight(x) {
  if (x.css('position') == "absolute") {
    let height = parseFloat(x.css('height')) + parseFloat(x.css('top'));
    if (height < parseFloat(x.parent().css('height'))) {
      return parseFloat(x.parent().css('height'))
    }
    return height;
  }
}

console.log(getHeight($('article')))
```

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: red;
}

.bg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 15%;
  top: 100px;
  right: 10%;
  background: green;
}

article {
  position: absolute;
  width: 35%;
  top: 200px;
  right: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class='bg'></div>
  <article class='txt'>Sed id erat dolor. Etiam fermentum ac nibh at faucibus. Suspendisse in mauris sodales, aliquet arcu mollis, viverra lacus. Sed enim nibh, bibendum a tortor quis, feugiat viverra orci. Nam rutrum interdum purus, eget fermentum lorem porta non. Sed maximus
    erat enim, a mattis quam convallis in. Donec congue semper augue, vel tincidunt eros auctor placerat.</article>
</section>
```

To get all heights of the relative sections in the pages that have an absolute child

```
var sec = $('section');
var heights = [];
$.each(sec, (i, v) => {    
  if ($(sec[v]).css('position') == "relative") {
     console.log('ye')
     heights.push(getHeight($(sec[v]).find("article")));
  }
});
```

Comment: It is an incredible job! Today I do not have time anymore, but tomorrow I will check it.

Comment: Hello @Sarout, unfortunately it does not work. Now, one section is still collapsed, the other one has a height which is even less than the article height. 
I am not a js or jquery expert, but I do not see that this code would calculate the bottom of the last absolute positioned element, and would be the also the bottom of the section (this case section would not be collapsed). Is this what you understood from my question ?

Comment: nope, I'm sorry but I've understood that you want to calculate this section's height (*which is you can't get it from computed style or anywhere because they calculate only section tag's height, and because article is absolute position somewhy the section will not shrink to wrap the article, so I've summarized top and height*),

Comment: I do not know how to enclose an image here, I edit my post to put image there.

Comment: one last thing, I hope it doesn't bother you, but should the last absolute positioned element in the result (or page) be the last element in HTML too? in another word, the last one declared or written in HTML or just it's  the farest one from the top

Comment: I do not know yet what will be the last element in the whole document/html. What I know is that I have several sections which are collapsed because of their absolute positioned children, but I need sections having calculated heights for better calculation of positioning.
Maybe it can not be solved, that is why I did not find result on the web, it is possible...